# Will this fork crown race installation tool work?

Tags: repair, fork, shopping

I am looking to purchase a fork crown race installation tool, ant this one is the only one available online. The IceToolz thing is "to be delivered" someday.

I am very skeptical of this tool, as it does not allow the user to hummer it with a hummer. How well would it work?

[image]

Comment: Is it stated in user manual, that you can not use hammer?

Comment: @Papuass, no idea. [Here](http://proftools.net/product/882/dornik-za-nabivane-na-konus-na-vilkata-unior-1615-4.html) is the on-line shop. I cannot find a manual. Code: 615526
Manufacturer: UNIOR. It's just that the tool does not stick above the tube like the [proper tool](http://www.parktool.com/product/crown-race-setting-system-crs-1)

Comment: I think you can still use your hammer, just go around the circle with small bumps. This procedure does not need much force.

Comment: @Papuass, I guess I could either hit the tool on the edges with a hummer, or hit the crown race with the tool. But how good will this be compared to the ParkTools one? Until now I have done it without any specialized tools and the results have been quite poor.

Comment: Last time I did this, I used a foot of PVC pipe, it really doesn't need much force to get it all snug.

Comment: @alex, what diameter for 1 1/8 fork? In mm preferably.

Comment: I forget, I took the race to the shop with me and compared them.

Comment: @alex, I did the pipe method and it worked fine. Now tell me, how am I going to select an answer to accept?

Comment: andy's is correct I suppose. let him have it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work; I have used similar tools successfully.

The [page](http://proftools.net/product/882/dornik-za-nabivane-na-konus-na-vilkata-unior-1615-4.html) says that the tool is 0.5 kg (1.1 lb) of tool steel.

You use *it* as the hammer, gently tapping the race into place.